# Complex analysis integrals on path cos(z) power five

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometric-integrals

I m looking for the way to calculate this kind of integrals :

1)For t $ \in$ [0, 2$\pi$], We have $\gamma(t)= e^{it}$ and we want to calculate the integral on the path $\gamma$

a) $\int_{\gamma} \cos^5 \left(z\right) \, dz$

b) $\int_{\gamma} \frac {\cos^5 \left(z\right)} {z} \, dz$

c) $\int_{\gamma} \frac {\cos^5 \left(z\right)} {z^2} \, dz$

i first wanted to write it but i'm blocked

a) We have $\gamma(t)= e^{it}$ So  $\gamma'(t)= ie^{it}$

So $\int_{\gamma} \cos^5 \left(z\right) \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^5 \left(e^{it}\right) \left(ie^{it}\right)\, dz$

then i don't know how to do...

thank you for your help !

Comment: Do you know thing like residue theorem? They can conveniently calculate these kind of closed-path integrals

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's theorem? Cauchy's integral formula? Cauchy's integral formula for derivatives?

Comment: thank you for answering, yes i just learned them recently. But i don't practice with exercice yet. So which one of them do i use ? thank you very much again for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\cos^5(z)$ is an entire function.  Hence from [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem), for any rectifiable closed contour $C$, we have

$$\oint_C \cos^5(z)\,dz=0 \tag 1$$

Note that $(1)$ is true for any entire function $f(z)$.  In fact, if $f$ is analytic in and on the rectifiable closed curve $C$, then

$$\oint_C f(z)\,dz=0 $$

---

From [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem), if $f$ is analytic in and on the rectifiable closed curve $C$, then

$$\oint_C \frac{f(z')}{(z'-z)^{n+1}}\,dz'=2\pi i \frac{f^{(n)}(z)}{n!}$$

Therefore, we can assert that

$$\oint_\gamma \frac{\cos^5(z)}{z}\,dz=2\pi i \cos^5(0)$$

and

$$\oint_\gamma \frac{\cos^5(z)}{z^2}\,dz=2\pi i \left.\left(\frac{d\cos^5(z)}{dz}\right)\right|_{z=0}$$

Can you finish the details?

Comment: hi Mark thank you a lot for your explanation, but I didn't understand at the end why you evaluate $2\pi i cos(z)^5$ in zero ? and why the last line you want to derivate $cos^5(z)$ ?

Comment: Apply Cauchy's Integral Formula with $n=0$ and $n=1$, respectively.

Comment: yes but why z= 0 ?

Comment: Look at Cauchy's Integral Formula.  Set $z=0$.

Comment: Of course but when i tried they said me this "feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: i did it thank you again

Comment: You're welcome Farouk.